# InvalidCastException while no compile errors with upcasting

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, casting

What I'm basically trying to do is Convert Objects I get from a web Service to objects that are compatible with my Entity Framework object. I though of doing this by creating an Interface that both is applied to the web service objects & the EF objects. That way I can easily cast from one type to the other.
At this point I have the following object: A, A1, B and interface IAB.

The problem I'm no facing is when I do an upcast from object A to A1 I get a Run-time error but no compile errors. I would like to know why my upcast isn't accepted?

```
public class A
{
  //Has variables & Properties
}

public class A1 : A, IAB
{
  //Has some properties
}
```

**Note:** I needed to create A1 as extending the partial class A created Serialization problems for the web service. So this seemed to be the best solution.

When contacting the service I ask for a list of A objects and then want to upcast them to A1. Later I will cast them into B.

I try to cast the objects like this:

```
 List<A1> allA1 = new List<A1>();
 foreach (A item in retrievedListOfA)
 {      
     allA1.Add((A1)item); 
 }
```

As I don't get any compile errors I find it strange that I get this error. if I do a check of the type "A is A1" then it never goes in that if statement.

Can someone point out to me why this is creating problems? Is it because object A is from a web service?

**Note**: If this method of "Porting" object from one to another is totally absurd please give me some directions how it should be done. It is the first time I'm attempting something like this.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the objects coming from a webservice directly. I'd consider creating a local Entity(say localA) for "A". Also inheriting from an object coming from webservice is a bad idea.

Comment: Check what is the type of `item` at the time of Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get any compile errors, because (A1)item, is you saying to the compiler, I know what I'm doing so shut up.

So if retrievedListOfA is a collection of As and A1s, every A you cast to an A1, that is in fact an A and then call an A1 method on will blow up.

There are lots of porting methods, e.g. a converter, casting is not one of them.

Comment: Casting is indeed not a approach, Thanks for the advice! I took a look at the Converter and it works really good. you do need to map the properties (in the delegate method) yourself but that's no problem for my solution.
For people with bigger object might find this useful: http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 1):

[Tony Hopkinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17729016/1518265) is right about the reason you are getting the current error. But, it does not currently address the larger issue you hint at.

> Quote: Oxillery
>
> **Note:** If this method of "Porting" object from one to another is totally absurd
>   pleasegive me some directions how it should be done. It is the first time I'm attempting
>   something like this.

It appears that you are receiving a collection of serialized class instances (from a web service), and want to make them into entity framework compatible objects. I believe your issues arise because there is inconsistency between the serialization and deserialization of your instances.

Take the following simple class (our desired Entity Framework entity):

```
public class Dog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique ID of this dog, aka the number printed on the dog's implanted microchip.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The embarassing number of homeworks shredded.
    /// </summary>
    public long ShreddedHomeworks { get; set; }
}
```

Based on your statement, you are receiving from a web service some kind of other object that you want to convert to a Dog. Suppose the class that you are receiving looks like the following:

```
public class PseudoDog
{
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Legs { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that that the two classes are not *directly* compatible in terms of serializing a PseudoDog and deserializing it as a Dog. I purposely made the PseudoDog have 'Legs' as a property and Dog have 'ShreddedHomeworks' so that without manipulation, they cannot be converted.

The basis for how they can be converted is from the [Web API tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-6) about data transfer objects (DTO's) and their use. Continuing the example above, the class used to convert a PseudoDog to a Dog would look like the following:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class DogDTO
{
    #region Static Methods

    public static Dog ToDog(DogDTO dto)
    {
        // if the data transfer object is null
        // we cannot make a Dog from it.
        if (dto == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Dog dog = new Dog();

        // We can be sure of what these values are intended to be.
        dog.Name = dto.Name;
        dog.Birthday = dto.Birthday;

        return dog;
    }

    public static DogDTO CreateFrom(Dog dog)
    {
        if (dog == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        DogDTO dto = new DogDTO();

        dto.Name = dog.Name;
        dto.Birthday = dog.Birthday;
    }

    #endregion

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The juicy bits of DogDTO are two properties at the bottom (*Birthday* and *Name*) which have the DataMember attribute. This means that the DogDTO class can be serialized and deserialized with the DataContractSerializer.

Putting all the pieces together, the entire process looks like this:

1. Some client makes a PseudoDog instance named 'Fido'
2. The client serializes 'Fido' (to XML, JSON, binary, etc...) to file named 'serialdog.xml'.
3. The client sends the webservice the 'serialdog.xml' file.
4. The webservice that receives 'serialdog.xml' deserializes it into a DogDTO instance (named 'FidoDTO')
5. Your method calls DogDTO.ToDog(FidoDTO) which returns a new Dog instance named 'myFido'.
6. You can now use the Dog instance 'myFido' as it is an Entity Framework entity.

Succintly, conversion goes like this:

```
Web Service object --> object DTO --> Entity Framework compliant object
```

---

Under the following assumptions that

> Type A - the Type of the instance from web service
>
> Type A1 - the Type of your current conversion instance
>
> Type B - the Type of the instance used by Entity Framework

and

> Type A_DTO - the Type of the data transfer object

You should make the following changes wherever it is you have this code:

```
List<A1> allA1 = new List<A1>();
foreach (A item in retrievedListOfA)
{      
     allA1.Add((A1)item); 
}
```

I would replace it with this:

```
List<B> allB = new List<B>();
foreach (A_DTO dto in retrievedListofA_DTO)
{
    allB.Add(A_DTO.ToB(dto));
}
```